# Как в яндекс плагине сделать так чтобы шёл счёт времени до рекламы на сцене, но в самой сцене реклама не показывалась

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как в яндекс плагине сделать так чтобы шёл счёт времени до рекламы на сцене, но в самой сцене реклама не показывалась. Я понимаю что можно просто удалить префаб с рекламой, но тогда на этой сцене не будет идти счёт времени до следующей рекламы, а это игровая сцена, где будет проходить большая часть игры.

Comment: Зачем удалять префаб? Используйте Instantiate, добавляйте объект динамически на сцену управляющим скриптом, им же и время считайте, им же и объект уничтожайте. Не вешайте скрипты на саму рекламу. Можно ещё setActive попробовать.